# Recording data over time in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is a very general question I don't seem to find an answer to. Let's say I have a model called Room referring to a hotel room. And I would like to have a time series showing me room occupation in the past, present and future.

One "thought" I had was to have a dictionary with something like {'date': room.guest} but I don't see how I can define a dict for a Django Model. Is this approach realisable within Django at all? What kind of alternatives do I have to achieve this goal?

Currently my Room Model is very simple and looks like this:

```
class Room(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField()

    room_type = models.ForeignKey('RoomType')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Room {}".format(self.number)
```

The Room itself is a Foreign Key in the Guest Model..

Answer (score 0):

Django models are just wrappers (smart wrappers but still only wrappers) above db tables. The obvious solution here is to think how you'd design this feature at the relational database level, then write it as a Django model. IOW : you want a db table that will store "occupations":

```
class Occupation(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest)
    date = models.DateField(...)

# etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With this approach I can't seem to display the data the way i want. Where I have a view that gets passed month and year from the url and then has to iterate over rooms and dates and display occupation data. So let's say i filter the occupation for month and year and pass this to the template and I also pass a list of the days and rooms to the template. I then use for loops over room and day to fill the tables. How can I make the template get occupation.is_occupied for occupation.date__day=day and occupation.room=room?

Comment: Don't put your logic in the template - it belongs to either the models and/or the view(s).

Comment: can you give me some advice on how to achieve that? As far as I can see I put no logic in the template...I just want it to display the values of certain variable.. which is kind of what templates do, right?

Comment: I was thinking about your "How can I make the template get occupation.is_occupied for occupation.date__day=day and occupation.room=room" question and "I also pass a list of the days and rooms to the template" - actually, you shouldn't pass distinct lists and querysets to the context and try to match them in the template, but do all the necessary grouping /  matching / sorting etc in the view (or in the models) so what you pass to the template already has the correct data structure.

Comment: I finally managed to get the output the way I wanted using your suggested approach. Thank you. Unfortunately my code is not DRY at all but at least it works. Thank you.